# Best way to add/use directories inside of /msg?

Tags: ros, catkin, generate-messages, msg, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, and I can't seem to find any answers involving this. I'm working with a relatively large project with hundreds of messages, and there's no way it's reasonable to just put them all in the base msg directory. However, I can't find any reasonable way to implement multiple directories which rely on eachother using the catkin build system/default CMake macros given. I'd rather not have to create many packages containing only messages, it seems like creating a hierarchy would be difficult that way and it doesn't make sense.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214876/best-way-to-add/use-directories-inside-of-/msg?/) by [anything234](https://answers.ros.org/users/23395/anything234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be abled to call `add_message_files(...)` multiple times with different DIRECTORY arguments:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/genmsg/html/usermacros.html

Have you tried that?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2